# Why wont the controls on my slider respond to my cursor and why isn't my console logging anything?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I am new to coding and programming and I have been following, on Youtube, a screen recording of a programmer making a responsive thumbnail slider using HTML, CSS, and Javascript.
I've gotten to a point where I am trying to get "0" to show up in my console when I click the controls for the slider, but I can't get the controls to respond to my cursor.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? My code is below.

```js
const controls=document.querySelector(".artcontrols");
 const container=document.querySelector(".thumbnailcontainer");
 const allBox=container.children;
 const containerWidth=container.offsetWidth;
 const margin=30;
 var item=0;
 var totalItems=0;
 
 // item setup per slide
 
 responsive=[
 {breakPoint:{width:0,item:1}}, //if width greater than 0 (1 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:600,item:2}}, //if width greater than 600 (2 will item show)
 {breakPoint:{width:1000,item:6}} //if width greater than 1000 (4 will item show)
 ]
 
 function load(){
  for(let i=0; i<responsive.length;i++){
   if(window.innerWidth>responsive[i].breakPoint.width){
    items=responsive[i].breakPoint.item
   }
  }
  start();
 }
 
 function start(){
  var totalItemsWidth=0
  for(let i=0;i<allBox.length;i++){
   //width and margin setup of items
   allBox[i].style.width=(containerWidth/items)-margin + "px";
   allBox[i].style.margin=(margin/2)+ "px";
   totalItemsWidth+=containerWidth/items;
   totalItems++;
  }
  //tumbnail-container width set up
  container.style.width=totalItemsWidth + "px";
  
  //slides controls number set up
   const allSlides=Math.ceil(totalItems/items);
   const ul=document.createElement("ul");
   for(let i=1;i<=allSlides;i++){
     const li=document.createElement("li");
     li.id=i;
     li.innerHTML=i;
     li.setAttribute("onclick","controlSlides(this)");
     ul.appendChild(li);
     if(i==1){
      li.className="active";
     }
   }
   controls.appendChild(ul);
 }
 
 //when clicked numbers slide to next slide
 function controlSlides(ele){
  //select controls children 'ul' element
  const ul=controls.children;
  
  //select ul children 'li' elements;
   const li=ul[0].children;
  
  //find who is now active
  var active;
  
  for(let i=0;i<li.length;i++){
   if(li[i].className=="active"){
    //find who is now active
    active=i;
    console.log(active)
   }
  }
 }
 
 window.onload=load();
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumbnailslider {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbanilslider .thumbnailcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.thumbnailslider .artitem {
 height: 175px;
 background-color: grey;
 line-height: 175px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #ffffff;
 float: left;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding: 15px;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li {
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
 margin: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 33px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnailslider .artcontrols ul li.active{
 background-color: green;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnailslider">
   <div class="thumbnailcontainer">
    <div class="artitem">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    7
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    8
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    9
    </div>
    <div class="artitem">
    10
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Control Slides -->
   <div class="artcontrols">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's working right here in Stack Overflow. Have you tried your own code right in this question?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did run the code in the question and it worked but when I tried it in the browser it didn't work.

Comment: Then, there is clearly an issue that's not related to the actual code. Have you turned on the developer's tools (F12) and looked at the Console tab for error messages?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have but it doesn't show any errors.